# How to tabulate columns in a data frame and put the results in a single data frame

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have a data frame of 400 rows and 1200 columns, and the general structure is like this:

```
> df=data.frame(Col1=paste0('row',1:15),metric1=sample(c('H','M','L'),15,replace = 1),metric2=sample(c('H','M'),15,replace = 1))
> df
    Col1 metric1 metric2 ...
1   row1       M       H
2   row2       H       L
```

What I would like to do is compare the tabular outcome of each row based on the counts of HML for each column.

I tried

```
> apply(df[,2:3],2,function(x) table(x))
$metric1
x
H L M 
1 7 7 

$metric2
x
 H  M 
10  5 

>
```

But the result is a list of 1200 because not all of the column contain all 3 values, ie one column only has HL, while another will have HML.

I also tried aggregate, which lead to an error

```
> apply(df[,2:3],2,function(x) aggregate(df$count,list(df[,x]),sum))
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , x) : undefined columns selected
```

but my function works:

```
> aggregate(df$count,list(df[,2]),sum)
  Group.1 x
1       H 1
2       L 7
3       M 7
>
```

I was hoping to save it as a data frame such as:

```
> data.frame(var=c('H','M','L'),metric1=c(100,100,200),metric2=c(250,150,0))
  var metric1 metric2
1   H     100     250
2   M     100     150
3   L     200       0
>
```

Comment: Do you have only those 3 categories (H, L, M), or something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you don't want to use a loop, you can also assign the levels in the table function:

```
apply(df[,2:3],2,function(x) table(factor(x,levels=c("H","M","L"))))

    metric1 metric2
H       6      11
M       8       4
L       1       0
```

Comment: Note that `apply` is using a `for` loop under the hood and is typically slower than a properly implemented `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, lmo!  I didn't know that!   Though, if the other solution then calls sapply after the for loop, would it still be faster (if presumably sapply is still running a for loop under the hood as well)?  Thanks for any insight! :)

Comment: The canonical answer is that it depends. A second "issue" with `apply` is that it converts (a copy of) its main argument to a matrix prior to implementing the supplied function. Here, this involves conversion from a list of factors to a matrix of character vectors, the columns of which are then re-converted into factors, one at a time. This is a pretty costly set of operations on large datasets, which a `for` loop can avoid. You can see this conversion to character with `apply(df[,2:3], 2, function(x) x)`.

Comment: Good to know!  I have recently had it ingrained in me that for loops are to be avoided whenever possible (they used to be my stand by) and have been trying to use other methods to be more efficient. Now I know the apply functions may not be the best way to do that... :)

Comment: `for` loops can be among the fastest methods depending on what you are doing. Growing objects in a loop is the biggest mistake that most people make early on and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain!  Yes, I had rbinding in some of my loops... :0

Comment: I like this one as it uses an apply, which I also thought was more efficient than for loops, and it looks nice and neat too :) But after what Imo said, it depends, and I will need to look into which is better under what situations

Comment: Maybe a small improvement: `table.fun <- function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c('H','M','L'))); sapply(df[2:3], table.fun)`

Answer (score 2):

I would ensure all `table` lead to 3 categories by first converting metrics to factors having H, L, M as levels.

This leads to:

```
df=data.frame(Col1=paste0('row',1:15),metric1=sample(c('H','M','L'),15,replace = 1),metric2=sample(c('H','M'),15,replace = 1))
for (i in 2:ncol(df)){
  df[[i]] <- factor(df[[i]],levels=c("H","M","L"))
}
```

Then on call apply table on every columns and stack:

```
sapply(df[-1],table)
      metric1 metric2
H       3       8
M       1       7
L      11       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
sumer <- function(data, pattern)
{
        temp <- colSums(sapply(pattern, grepl, data))
        names(temp) <- pattern
        temp
}


apply(df[, 2:3], 2, sumer, unique(df[, 2]))
```